# Apache tomcat catalina springsource bundle is not RESOLVED on equinox OSGi container

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, catalina, springsource, osgi-fragment

I have a java application in which I start Equinox OSGi container (version 3.10.1.v20140909-1633) and load apache catalina springsource bundle `com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956` and other dependent bundles. 
Following is my config.ini file.

```
eclipse.ignoreApp=true

# custom org.osgi.framework.system.packages to export javax.activation and javax.xml.bind.* with a non-0.0.0 version
 org.osgi.framework.system.packages=javax.accessibility; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.activation; version="1.1.0", \
    javax.activity; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.annotation; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.annotation.processing; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.crypto; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.crypto.interfaces; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.crypto.spec; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.imageio; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.imageio.event; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.imageio.metadata; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.imageio.plugins.bmp; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.imageio.spi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.imageio.stream; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.jws; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.jws.soap; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.lang.model; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.lang.model.element; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.lang.model.type; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.lang.model.util; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.loading; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.modelmbean; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.monitor; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.openmbean; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.relation; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.remote; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.remote.rmi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.management.timer; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.naming; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.naming.directory; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.naming.event; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.naming.ldap; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.naming.spi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.net; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.net.ssl; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.print; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.print.attribute; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.print.attribute.standard; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.print.event; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.rmi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.rmi.CORBA; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.rmi.ssl; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.script; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.auth; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.auth.callback; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.auth.kerberos; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.auth.login; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.auth.spi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.auth.x500; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.cert; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.security.sasl; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sound.midi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sound.midi.spi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sound.sampled; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sound.sampled.spi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sql; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sql.rowset; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sql.rowset.serial; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.sql.rowset.spi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.border; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.colorchooser; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.event; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.filechooser; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.plaf; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.plaf.basic; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.plaf.metal; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.plaf.multi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.plaf.synth; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.table; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.text; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.text.html; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.text.html.parser; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.text.rtf; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.tree; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.swing.undo; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.tools; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.transaction; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.transaction.xa; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.bind; version="2.1.0", \
    javax.xml.bind.annotation; version="2.1.0", \
    javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters; version="2.1.0", \
    javax.xml.bind.attachment; version="2.1.0", \
    javax.xml.bind.helpers; version="2.1.0", \
    javax.xml.bind.util; version="2.1.0", \
    javax.xml.crypto; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.crypto.dom; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.crypto.dsig; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.datatype; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.namespace; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.parsers; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.soap; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.stream; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.stream.events; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.stream.util; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.transform; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.transform.dom; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.transform.sax; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.transform.stax; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.transform.stream; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.validation; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.ws; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.ws.handler; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.ws.handler.soap; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.ws.http; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.ws.soap; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.ws.spi; version="0.0.0", \
    javax.xml.xpath; version="0.0.0", \
     org.ietf.jgss; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CORBA; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CORBA_2_3; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CORBA.portable; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CORBA.TypeCodePackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CosNaming; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.Dynamic; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.DynamicAny; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyFactoryPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.IOP; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.IOP.CodecFactoryPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.IOP.CodecPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.Messaging; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableInterceptor; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableServer; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableServer.portable; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.PortableServer.ServantLocatorPackage; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.SendingContext; version="0.0.0", \
     org.omg.stub.java.rmi; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.bootstrap; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.css; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.events; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.html; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.ls; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.ranges; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.stylesheets; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.traversal; version="0.0.0", \
     org.w3c.dom.views; version="0.0.0", \
     org.xml.sax; version="0.0.0", \
     org.xml.sax.ext; version="0.0.0", \
     org.xml.sax.helpers; version="0.0.0"

#
# derby and mysql must appear before com.castiron.drivers
#
osgi.bundles=acme/org.apache.derbyclient-10.8.3.3.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.derby-10.8.3.3.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.castiron.drivers-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.openjpa-2.2.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.jpa.fragment-1.0.0.jar@1, \
    acme/com.springsource.serp-1.13.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.pool-1.5.3.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.xmlcommons-1.3.3.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.xml.soap-1.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/javax.xml.rpc-1.1.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.ejb-3.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.ejb.fragment-1.0.0.jar@1, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.management.j2ee-1.0.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/javax.jms-1.1.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.activemq-5.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.kahadb-5.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.camel-1.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.hadoop-2.2.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.javassist-3.13.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/net.sf.ehcache-1.6.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.hibernate-3.2.5.jar@1:start, \
    acme/javax.interceptor-1.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.webbeans-1.0.0.jar@3:start, \
    acme/org.stax-ex-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.xmlrpc-1.2.jar@:start, \
    acme/com.saaj-impl-1.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.jaxws-rt-2.1.7.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.xml-streambuffer-0.8.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.ibm.xml.xlxp-1.1.14.jar@1:start, \
    acme/antlr-2.7.7.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.commonj-1.1.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/net.sf.cglib-2.1.3.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections-3.2.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.io-1.4.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.log4j.fragment-1.0.0.jar@1, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.dom4j-1.6.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.jaxen-1.1.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.xml.stream-1.0.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm-1.5.3.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm.attrs-1.5.3.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-osgi-extender-1.2.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-osgi-core-1.2.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-osgi-io-1.2.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-core-2.5.6.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-context-2.5.6.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-beans-2.5.6.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-aop-2.5.6.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-web-2.5.6.jar@1:start, \
    acme/spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.slf4j.org.apache.commons.logging-1.5.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.slf4j.api-1.5.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.slf4j.log4j-1.5.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.el.springsource-6.0.20.S2-r5956.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.jasper.springsource-6.0.20.S2-r5956.jar@1, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.jasper.org.eclipse.jdt-6.0.16.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.juli.extras.springsource-6.0.20.S2-r5956.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.coyote.springsource-6.0.20.S2-r5956.jar@1, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.el-2.1.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.servlet-2.5.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp-2.1.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.1.2.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.el-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard-1.1.2.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.annotation-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.persistence-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.transaction-1.1.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.xml.ws-2.1.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/javax.mail-1.4.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource-6.0.20.S2-r5956.jar@5:start, \
    com.approuter.catalina.start-1.0.0.jar@5:start, \
    com.approuter.catalina.fragment-1.0.0.jar@5, \
    com.approuter.catalina.realm-1.0.0.jar@5:start, \
    com.approuter.spring.osgi.web.fragment-1.0.0.jar@6, \
    com.approuter.spring.osgi.web.extender.fragment-1.0.0.jar@6, \
    acme/spring-osgi-web-1.2.0.jar@6:start, \
    acme/spring-osgi-web-extender-1.2.0.jar@6:start, \
    com.approuter.system.configure-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.system.configure.analytics-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    wmc.war@7:start, \
    acme/net.sf.saxon-9.1.0.7.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.com.thoughtworks.xstream-1.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.com.lowagie.text-2.0.8.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.javax.management.j2ee-1.0.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec-1.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.fileupload-1.2.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.2.4.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.5.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang-2.4.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net-1.4.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.xbean.spring-3.3.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.xerces-2.8.1.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.apache.xml.resolver-1.2.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/org.quartz-1.8.6.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.quartz_scheduler-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.springsource.org.xmlpull-1.1.3.4-O.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.common-base-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.common-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.module.connectorrepository-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.deploy.arrepo-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.logging-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.maestro.sdk-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.maestro-1.0.0.jar@1, \
    com.approuter.module.common-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.orcmon-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    acme/com.xerox.amazonws.typica-1.6.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.sysconf-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.security-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.module.projects-1.0.0.jar@2:start, \
    com.approuter.module.thirdparty-1.0.0.jar@2:start, \
    com.approuter.module.manageappliances-1.0.0.jar@2:start, \
    com.approuter.agent.configuration-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.module.capacitymeter-1.0.0.jar@4, \
    acme/com.hector-0.7.0-31.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.agent.management-1.0.0.jar@1:start, \
    com.approuter.pki-1.0.0.jar@4:start, \
    com.approuter.module.pip.repository-1.0.0.jar@4:start, \
    org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start, \
    org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start

# start all bundles up to start level 8
osgi.startLevel=8
```

When I connect to OSGi console and list all bundles with `ss` command I see the following result

```
"Framework is launched."

id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633
                Fragments=1
1       RESOLVED    com.approuter.eclipse.osgi.fragment_1.0.0
                Master=0
2       ACTIVE      org.apache.derbyclient_10.8.3.3
3       ACTIVE      org.apache.derby_10.8.3.3
4       ACTIVE      com.castiron.drivers_1.0.0
5       ACTIVE      com.springsource.serp_1.13.1
6       ACTIVE      org.apache.commons-dbcp_1.2.2
7       ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.pool_1.5.3
8       ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.xmlcommons_1.3.3
9       ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.soap_1.3.0
10      ACTIVE      javax.xml.rpc_1.1.0
11      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.ejb_3.0.0
                Fragments=12
12      RESOLVED    com.approuter.ejb.fragment_1.0.0
                Master=11
13      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.management.j2ee_1.0.1
14      ACTIVE      javax.jms_1.1.0
15      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.activemq_5.3.0
16      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.kahadb_5.3.0
17      ACTIVE      org.apache.camel_1.3.0
18      ACTIVE      org.apache.hadoop_2.2.0
19      ACTIVE      org.javassist_3.13.0
20      ACTIVE      net.sf.ehcache_1.6.0
21      ACTIVE      org.hibernate_3.2.5
22      ACTIVE      javax.interceptor_1.1.0
23      ACTIVE      org.apache.webbeans_1.0.0
24      ACTIVE      org.stax-ex_1.0.0
25      ACTIVE      com.xmlrpc_1.2.0
26      ACTIVE      com.saaj-impl_1.3.0
27      ACTIVE      com.jaxb-impl_2.1.12
28      ACTIVE      com.jaxws-rt_2.1.7
29      ACTIVE      com.xml-streambuffer_0.8.0
30      ACTIVE      com.ibm.xml.xlxp_1.1.14
31      ACTIVE      antlr_2.7.7
32      ACTIVE      com.springsource.commonj_1.1.0
33      ACTIVE      net.sf.cglib_2.1.3
34      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections_3.2.1
35      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.io_1.4.0
36      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1
37      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.log4j_1.2.15
                Fragments=38
38      RESOLVED    com.approuter.log4j.fragment_1.0.0
                Master=37
39      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.dom4j_1.6.1
40      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.jaxen_1.1.1
41      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.stream_1.0.1
42      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm_1.5.3
43      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm.tree.attrs_1.5.3
44      ACTIVE      org.springframework.osgi.extender_1.2.0
45      ACTIVE      org.springframework.osgi.core_1.2.0
46      ACTIVE      org.springframework.osgi.io_1.2.0
47      ACTIVE      org.springframework.core_2.5.6
48      ACTIVE      org.springframework.context_2.5.6
49      ACTIVE      org.springframework.beans_2.5.6
50      ACTIVE      org.springframework.aop_2.5.6
51      ACTIVE      org.springframework.web_2.5.6
52      ACTIVE      org.springframework.web.servlet_2.5.6
53      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.aopalliance_1.0.0
54      ACTIVE      com.springsource.slf4j.org.apache.commons.logging_1.5.0
55      ACTIVE      com.springsource.slf4j.api_1.5.0
56      ACTIVE      com.springsource.slf4j.log4j_1.5.0
57      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.el.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956
58      INSTALLED   com.springsource.org.apache.jasper.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956
59      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.jasper.org.eclipse.jdt_6.0.16
60      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.juli.extras.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956
61      INSTALLED   com.springsource.org.apache.coyote.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956
62      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.el_2.1.0
63      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.servlet_2.5.0
64      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp_2.1.0
65      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.1.2
66      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.el_1.0.0
67      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard_1.1.2
68      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.annotation_1.0.0
69      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.persistence_1.0.0
70      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.transaction_1.1.0
71      ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.ws_2.1.1
72      ACTIVE      javax.mail_1.4.0
73      INSTALLED   com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956
74      INSTALLED   com.approuter.catalina.start_1.0.0
75      INSTALLED   com.approuter.catalina.fragment_1.0.0
76      ACTIVE      com.approuter.catalina.realm_1.0.0
77      RESOLVED    com.approuter.spring.osgi.web.fragment_1.0.0
                Master=79
78      RESOLVED    com.approuter.spring.osgi.web.extender.fragment_1.0.0
                Master=80
79      ACTIVE      org.springframework.osgi.web_1.2.0
                Fragments=77
80      RESOLVED    org.springframework.osgi.web.extender_1.2.0
                Fragments=78
81      ACTIVE      com.approuter.system.configure_1.0.0
82      ACTIVE      com.approuter.system.configure.analytics_1.0.0
85      INSTALLED   com.approuter.nmc_0.0.0
86      ACTIVE      net.sf.saxon_9.1.0.7
87      ACTIVE      org.apache.xmlbeans_2.4.0
88      ACTIVE      com.springsource.com.thoughtworks.xstream_1.3.0
89      ACTIVE      com.springsource.com.lowagie.text_2.0.8
90      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec_1.3.0
91      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.2.0
92      ACTIVE      org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.4.0
93      ACTIVE      org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.4.0
94      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang_2.4.0
95      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net_1.4.1
96      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.xbean.spring_3.3.0
97      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.xerces_2.8.1
98      ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.xml.resolver_1.2.0
99      ACTIVE      org.quartz_1.8.6
100     ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.xmlpull_1.1.3.4-O
101     ACTIVE      com.approuter.common-base_1.0.0
102     ACTIVE      com.approuter.common_1.0.0
103     ACTIVE      com.approuter.module.connectorrepository_1.0.0
104     ACTIVE      com.approuter.deploy.arrepo_1.0.0
     ACTIVE      com.approuter.logging_1.0.0
106     ACTIVE      com.approuter.maestro.sdk_1.0.0
107     RESOLVED    com.approuter.maestro_1.0.0
108     ACTIVE      com.approuter.module.common_1.0.0
109     ACTIVE      com.approuter.orcmon_1.0.0
110     ACTIVE      com.xerox.amazonws.typica_1.6.0
111     ACTIVE      com.approuter.sysconf_1.0.0
113     ACTIVE      com.approuter.module.projects_1.0.0
114     ACTIVE      com.approuter.module.thirdparty_1.0.0
115     ACTIVE      com.approuter.module.manageappliances_1.0.0
116     ACTIVE      com.approuter.agent.configuration_1.0.0
117     RESOLVED    com.approuter.module.capacitymeter_1.0.0
118     ACTIVE      com.hector_0.7.0.31
119     ACTIVE      com.approuter.agent.management_1.0.0
120     RESOLVED    com.approuter.pki_1.0.0
121     ACTIVE      com.approuter.module.pip.repository_1.0.0
122     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505
123     ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
124     ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
125     ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
126     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.0.v20140131-1639
127     ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.fileinstall_3.4.0
128     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.4.0.v20140312-2051
```

Here the bundles `com.springsource.org.apache.jasper.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956` and  `com.springsource.org.apache.coyote.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956` are fragment bundles whose parent bundle is `com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956`.

We can see that all these 3 bundles are just INSTALLED.
When I tried to start the bundle `com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956` manually with the command `start 73`, I see following exception.

```
gogo: BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource [73]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.coyote; version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956,6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
    -> Export-Package: org.apache.coyote; bundle-version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.springsource.org.apache.coyote.springsource"; version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; uses:="javax.management,org.apache.tomcat.util.buf,org.apache.tomcat.util.http,org.apache.tomcat.util.net"
       com.springsource.org.apache.coyote.springsource [61]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.catalina.deploy; version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956,6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
           -> Export-Package: org.apache.catalina.deploy; bundle-version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource"; version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.catalina; version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956,6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
           -> Export-Package: org.apache.catalina; bundle-version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource"; version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; uses:="javax.naming.directory,javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,org.apache.catalina.connector,org.apache.catalina.deploy,org.apache.catalina.util,org.apache.juli.logging,org.apache.tomcat,org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper"
         Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource; bundle-version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956,6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource; bundle-version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.coyote.http11; version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956,6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
    -> Export-Package: org.apache.coyote.http11; bundle-version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.springsource.org.apache.coyote.springsource"; version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; uses:="javax.management,org.apache.coyote,org.apache.tomcat.util.buf,org.apache.tomcat.util.net"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.coyote.ajp; version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956,6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
    -> Export-Package: org.apache.coyote.ajp; bundle-version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.springsource.org.apache.coyote.springsource"; version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; uses:="javax.management,org.apache.coyote,org.apache.tomcat.util.buf,org.apache.tomcat.util.net"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.tomcat; version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956,6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
    -> Export-Package: org.apache.tomcat; bundle-version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; bundle-symbolic-name="com.springsource.org.apache.jasper.springsource"; version="6.0.20.S2-r5956"; uses:="javax.servlet"
       com.springsource.org.apache.jasper.springsource [58]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.tools.ant; version="[1.7.0,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs; version="[1.7.0,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.tools.ant.types; version="[1.7.0,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.tools.ant.util; version="[1.7.0,2.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource; version="[6.0.20.S2-r5956, 6.0.20.S2-r5956]"
```

But when I looked at the Import and Export packages of both coyote and Jasper bundles, its proper. In fact they are taken from springsource repository.

I did not get the missing constraints for the bundle `com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956`.

Here which bundle will be resolved first ? Is it parent bundle or fragments ? 
How do I resolve this to make sure all the bundles are resolved and successfully start the bundle `com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.springsource_6.0.20.S2-r5956`

Comment: might be interested in the Pax Web Project, it uses either Jetty or Tomcat and is a mediation layer for working with Http Services in OSGi.

Comment: It works when deployed on OSGi container v3.4.0.v20080605-1900. But it fails to resolve when deployed on OSGi 3.10.1.v20140909-1633. Are there any changes with respect to fragment bundle resolution in OSGi v3.10.1?

Answer (score 0):

Parent bundles are resolved first.  After the parents are resolved than fragments get attached to their respective parents. I'd suggest to use latest [equinox](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/) jar as well. It's easier to resolve these kind of errors by debugging using equinox shell commands. For example, in your case you can check who is exporting the package "org.apache.coyote" by using the command `packages org.apache.coyote`.

Comment: I tried with latest equinox version as well. I still get same error. I have debugged it from console. Everything looks fine. All the required bundles are exported properly. It works in older OSGi and not working in newer OSGi spec means something might have changed with respect to the way OSGi resolves bundle and constraints.